# Attempt to assign property "PName" on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backend, laravel-8

I'm making a CRUD App, Everything is working fine except Updation. I want to update data in my MySQL table.

Controller code:

```
function update(Request $req){

    $ID = $req->get('update_id');
    $Name = $req->get('update_name');
    $Price = $req->get('update_price');
    $new_prod = product::find($ID);
    $new_prod->PName = $Name;
    $new_prod->PPrice = $Price;
    echo $new_prod;
    $new_prod->save();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Update Blade code:

```
<form action="updatedata" method="get">
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="">Product ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{$pid}}" name="update_id" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="">Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$pname}}" name="update_name">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="">Product Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{$price}}" name="update_price">
    </div>
   
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning rounded-pill">Update</button>
</form>
```

SQL QUERY:

```
select * from `products` where `products`.`Id` is null limit 1
```

Comment: What is the proble? You only show a select query, no update query?

Comment: `$new_prod = product::find($ID);` doesn't seem to return an object, but rather `null` (most likely the `$ID` is invalid/not found in the DB), which makes this: `$new_prod->PName` throw that error (since `$new_prod` is in fact `null`). Do some Never assume a DB query always returns what you expect. Double check it before using the result. Do some debugging to check if all data you get from the request actually contains what you think they do.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Please do not use irrelevant tags - or explain how the problem itself is related to MySQL itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$new_prod` variable is `null`, meaning the result of `product::find($ID);` is null. The reason for this likely being Laravel could not find a record in your database with the given `Id`.

If you trace things backwards to where you set `$ID`, you're getting it from your `$request` object (note it is good practice to never assume user input is always invalid and therefore [validate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation) incoming data) which suggests the value you're getting for `$ID` from your `$request` is invalid.

If you take it back another step and look at your `<form>` and the `update_id` `input`, you've set the `input` to `disabled`. Fields flagged with the `disabled` attribute are not sent in the request when the form is submitted. Therefore, replace `disabled` with `readonly`. That should allow the `update_id` to be submitted with the `<form>`.

It would also be a good idea to perform some checks after you've performed your `find` query for a `product` to ensure it actually has a value before you go using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function update(Request $req){

    $ID = $req->get('update_id');
    $Name = $req->get('update_name');
    $Price = $req->get('update_price');

    $new_prod = product::find($ID);
    if ($new_prod) {
        $new_prod->update([
          'PName' => $Name,
          'PPrice' => $Price  

        ]);
    }else{
        echo "No data found for this " +$ID;
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($ID!=null || $ID!=""){
 DB::table('products')->where('id', $ID)->update([
  'db_product_column_name_name' => $Name,
  'db_product_column_price_name' => $Price,
 ]);
}else{
 dd("ID null");
}
```

Check if the ID is null or empty and update if it is.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: btw, `"" == null`

Answer (score 0):

This code is not secure!
You must reassure yourself that update_id is present, and check that for the value $ID a record exists in the database. [Laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation) can help you

Nothing reassures that $ID exists, the $new_prod either. But you can try this:

You have to be sure that $new_prod exists and is not NULL before proceeding with the update in the database.

This code should help you

```
  function update(Request $req){

    $ID = intval($req->get('update_id')); //intval is not required
    $Name = $req->get('update_name');
    $Price = $req->get('update_price');
    //Will show a 404 error if a record doesn't exist
    $new_prod = product::findOrFail($ID);
    //the code can be executed
    $new_prod->PName = $Name;
    $new_prod->PPrice = $Price;
    // Don't do this, because you have a redirect below
    echo $new_prod;
    $new_prod->save();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can validation id first , like this:

```
$validator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), ['update_id' => 'required|integer|exists:tabel_name,id']);
if ($validator->fails()) {

$this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);

}
//your code
```